# Strange syntax error with jQuery.getJSON

Tags: jquery, json, syntax

I have got a JSON file for testing that looks like this:

```
[
    "http://lorempixel.com/g/1000/1000/fashion/",
    "http://lorempixel.com/g/1000/1000/nature/",
    "http://lorempixel.com/g/1000/1000/sports/",
    "http://lorempixel.com/g/1000/1000/technics/",
    "http://lorempixel.com/g/1000/1000/abstract/",
    "http://lorempixel.com/g/1000/1000/city/"
]
```

As far as I know this should represent an array of strings.

When I now try to load this Array:

```
$.getJSON(fileURL, function(json) {myFunction(json)});
```

I get a Syntax Error at the first `[`. When I try this with a JSON Object it says "not well-formed".

Wat do I do wrong?

**Edit**

The whole relevant code now is:

```
$('#input-button').click(function(){
    var url = $('#input-input').val();
    var json = $.getJSON(url);
    alert(json[0]);
});
```

Where `url` is the URL got from an `<input>`. The URL is right ("input.json" while the JSON and the HTML are in the same directory), I checked it. The JSON file looks exactly like above and linked in the comments.

**Edit2**

When I try:

```
$.getJSON(
   "input.json",
   function(json) {
      alert(json[0]);
});
```

I get my String but the error, too.

**Edit3**

I believe it's a brwoser/OS issue, now. I have a similar problem with getImageData() from a canvas context which works fine on other computers but noch on mine...

Comment: how you print this? If your output is exactly the same of your code, then it works for me.

Comment: The JSON you've quoted is just fine, and the call works: http://jsbin.com/usihoz/1 You'll have to walk through in a debugger to see what's actually going wrong, the question can't be answered in its current form.

Comment: Side note: You don't need `function(json) { myFunction(json)}`, you can just put `myFunction` there and have jQuery call it directly. But that's not why you're getting an error, it's just more concise.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder: Thanks for that last one. I've tried `myFunction(json)` but `json` wasn't defined of course.

EDIT: I'll try debugging but I think that won't work since the error apparently comes from within `getJSON`. My file is loaded properly, otherwise my browser couldn't point to the syntax error.

Comment: @Mouagip: Well, clearly there's something wrong with it (maybe a non-printable character preceding the `[`?), because what you've quoted is fine and `getJSON` works correctly as well. Good luck.

Comment: Can you post the URL of the JSON file if it's available online?

Comment: @pimvdb: [JSON file](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/56747969/input.json)

Comment: that's valid. The error is something else

Comment: Thanks, but what I actually meant was the original URL. It probably contains extraneous characters or is served with the wrong content type header.

Comment: @pimvdb: The original URL is "input.json". It's a local file in the same directory as the HTML. As I said above, now I get my Array (cerrectly) but the error remains.